# VBScript to check if there are files in a folder and if there are print them all

Tags: printing, vbscript, automation

I want a vbscript to check if there are files in a folder and if there are print them, wait a minute and move them to another folder wait another minute and delete them from the originating folder wait another minute and loop it. If there aren't any files in the folder wait a minute and loop. Here's what I already have:

```
PrintFolder = "C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Pending" 
LogFolder = "C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Completed"
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim wshell
Set wshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(PrintFolder) 
Set colItems = objFolder.Items()
If objFSO.FileExists("PrintFolder\*") Then
 For Each colItems in colItems
         If colItems.Name <> WScript.ScriptName Then
                 colItems.InvokeVerb "&Print"
         End If
 Next
 WScript.Sleep 60000
 objFSO.MoveFile "PrintFolder\*", "LogFolder"
 WScript.Sleep 60000
 objFSO.DeleteFile("PrintFolder\*")
 WScript.Sleep 60000
 wshell.Run("eprint.vbs")
Else
 WScript.Sleep 60000
 wshell.Run("eprint.vbs")
End If
```

EDIT: sorry I forgot to say that when I run this it doesn't print even though there are files in PrintFolder

Comment: Soooo... what's your question again?

Comment: When I run the script it doesn't print even though there is a file in PrintFolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually ask a question instead of making us guess your question.

```
If objFSO.FileExists("PrintFolder\*") Then
```

Wildcards not allowed here. Do a count of colitems instead.

Comment: So should I change "if file exists then" to "if colitems = >0 then"?

Comment: Yes you should. maybe If colitems.count > 0 Then

Comment: Is eprint.vbs the name of this script. If so put your whole script in a do ... loop instead.

Comment: Are your files moving, your syntax could be what you mean. E.G. objFSO.DeleteFile("PrintFolder\*") this delete files from a sub folder called PrintFolder of the default folder for the program. It is not C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Pending. objFSO.DeleteFile PrintFolder & "\\*"

Comment: Thanks, after pasting your script, changing the variable paths of the objFSO functions to static paths and changing the printing part of the script to "colItems.InvokeVerbEx ("Print")" it is finally working properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintFolder = "C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Pending" 
LogFolder = "C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Completed"
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim wshell
Set wshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Do

Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(PrintFolder) 
Set colItems = objFolder.Items()
If colitems.count > 0 Then
 For Each colItems in colItems
         If colItems.Name <> WScript.ScriptName Then
                 colItems.InvokeVerb "&Print"
         End If
 Next
 WScript.Sleep 60000
 objFSO.MoveFile "PrintFolder\*", "LogFolder"
 WScript.Sleep 60000
 objFSO.DeleteFile("PrintFolder\*")
End If 

WScript.Sleep 60000

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my now working script:

```
PrintFolder = "C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Pending" 
LogFolder = "C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Completed"
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim wshell
Set wshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Do

Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(PrintFolder) 
Set colItems = objFolder.Items()
If colItems.Count > 0 Then
 For Each colItems in colItems
     colItems.InvokeVerbEx ("Print")
 Next
 WScript.Sleep 60000
 objFSO.MoveFile "C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Pending\*", "C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Completed"
 WScript.Sleep 60000
 objFSO.DeleteFile("C:\Users\Bradley\Dropbox\PrintQueue\Pending\*")
End If 

WScript.Sleep 60000

Loop
```